# Eclipse installation error : an error has occurred. See the log file

Tags: java, eclipse, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, raspbian-stretch

I installed Eclipse IDE on my raspberry pi 3 with the command `apt-get install eclipse`. But when I run the program, a window spawns and said that an error has occured : [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alN3w.jpg)

```
An error has occurred.  See the log file
/home/pi/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1598129501217.log
```

This file doesn't exist...

I also tried to install Eclipse with the installer that we can find on eclipse.org but I cannot run the installer... [eclipse installer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QujNm.jpg)

Please, send help.

Answer (score 1):

The installer has not been compiled for ARM. It is only for Linux on x86-64 hardware and will not run on a Raspberry Pi.

Debian/Raspbian currently ship Eclipse 3.8, which was released back in 2012, and it is not compatible with JDKs from 2020. For now, you'll want to go to https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/ and directly download a 4.17 (or newer) build for Linux aarch64, such as the one under the "Eclipse SDK" part of the build's page, and unpack and use that.